# Getting array of instance_id from ruby AWS instanceCollection object

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm new to ruby (also to AWS) and  trying to create and populate `ELB` 
after creating EC2 instances

```
instances = ec2.instances.create(...)
```

I now need an array of theirs ID 
I need something like this (in `c#`)

```
list<string> ids = new list<string>

    Foreach (instance in instances)
    {
      ids.add(instance.id);
    }
    string [] id_Array = ids.toarray();
```

what is the fastest way to do it in Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `map` on your `instances` collection to use the `.id` method to create an array of `instance ids`.

```
instances = ec2.instances.create(...)
ids = instances.map(&:id)
```

#### References:

[AWS::EC2::Instance#id](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/EC2/Instance.html#id-instance_method)

[Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map)

Hope this helps